# how to make the input box become parralel or equal in form?

Tags: html, css, web

I can't figure how to make the box become parallel. and what tag or element should I use?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: You want to provide a bit of code so we can understand how you did your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Bootstrap CSS framework](https://getbootstrap.com/) to make a responsive layout. You can simply use the bootstrap grid system to make them label and form fields in a same line.

Below is an example of the form layout that you want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```